# A word that describes the act of running a company

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a word that describes the act of running a company? Preferably a single word.

Comment: The CEO "heads" the company.

Comment: Other verb possibilities: run, lead, drive, manage. For a noun: management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [management](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/management)

> The activity or job of being in charge of a company, organization, department, or team or employees.
>
> The control and organization of something, especially a business or company and its employees.